# Should I store the text used in label?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm pretty new to web development and currently I'm developing my front end using React JS.

so I have a component which render labels dynamically based on JSON data,

the JSON looks like this :

```
data:{
    name:"test123",
    toDoActivity:"coding",
}
```

and here is my code to render the labels

```
Object.entries(data).map((aData)=>{
    return <div>
              <label>{aData[0]} : {aData[1]}<label>
           </div>
})
```

now the code above will be rendered to

> name : test123
>
> toDoActivity : coding

here is the codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-microservice-s0sgy?file=/src/App.js

the data is rendered properly, but what I want is the data to be rendered with user friendly text like

> Name : test123
>
> To Do : coding

I have an idea to create a new attribute 'label text' in the JSON so it become like this :

```
data:{
    name:{value:"test123",text:"Name"},
    toDoActivity:{value:"coding",text:"To Do"},
}
```

but I don't know whether storing label's text like that is a good idea, so I come here to ask for your advice or better solution, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Object.values()` function. This is the correct way to show your desired result:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const theData = {
  name: { value: "test123", text: "Name" },
  toDoActivity: { value: "coding", text: "To Do" }
};
export default function App() {
  return Object.values(theData).map((aData) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>
          {aData.text} : {aData.value}
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  });
}
```

[This](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-grass-n0pp1?file=/src/App.js:0-373) is the edition of your code.

Comment: ah yes, that is what I was thinking about, but I wonder if it's efficient to store label's text in the json? since it will be stored in database eventually

Answer (score 0):

`Object.values` and `Object.entries` is just confusing here. Use an array of objects as your data:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const theData = [
  { value: "test123", text: "Name" },
  { value: "coding", text: "To Do" }
];
export default function App() {
  return theData.map((entry) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>
          {entry.text} : {entry.value}
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  });
}
```